# How to set width size of border

Tags: css

In my application's `<a>` tags I am using `border-bottom` property to show underline below links instead of using (`text-decoration:Underline;`) and it working fine but I want to show border-bottom one-half of link text on mobile and computer like:-

[image]

I tried `border-width` property to archive this but it increase its Thickness.

please suggest me how can i reduce its width? Thanks In advance

```css
nav ul li a {
                color: white !important;
                font-weight: 600;
            }

                nav ul li a:hover {
                    padding-bottom: 8px;
                    border-bottom: 4px solid #9d9d9d;
                }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #2f2f2f !important;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand swing" href="#" style="color:white; font-weight:600;font-variant:small-caps">Umang International School</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Examination</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help Desk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Addmission</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The `border-bottom` as far as it's on the `a:hover` is based on the width of the `a` itself. Please post the whole `css` for the `a` if there is any so we can see where the issue is from

Comment: Try @jones answer

Comment: I tried but not working when we have multiple links @OkeTega

Comment: Is that you want the border to be like the image you added to your question?

Comment: yes color can be change but i want same as image both in mobile and computer view

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element to create border.

```css
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 60%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}
a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Contect Us</a>
```

Comment: He wants it as an `hover effect`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `:after` element rather than adding a `border-bottom` to the link itself like this:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Contect Us</a>
```

Comment: He wants it as `hover effect` and this is good. Nice one

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `background-size` and add a `transition` and spare the pseudo for other purpose ;)

```css
a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  background:linear-gradient(black,black) no-repeat bottom center;
  background-size: 0% 1px ;  
  transition:0.25s
}
a:hover
{
  background:linear-gradient(black,black) no-repeat bottom center;
  background-size: 65% 4px ;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Contect Us</a>
```

Comment: On small size device it not working properly